# Python Pandas if/else Statement

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I am trying to write a nested `if/else` statement using pandas, but not very great with if statements in pandas. Please find the sample CSV data being processed and the sample code snippet I've written so far.

`df`:

```
t1  
8
1134
0
119
122
446
21
0
138 
0
```

Current if/else statement logic:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';')

def get_cost(df):
    t_zone = 720
    max_rate = 5.5
    rate = 0.0208
    duration = df['t1']

    if duration < t_zone:
        if(duration * rate) >= max_rate:
            return max_rate
        else:
            return(duration * rate)
    else:
        if duration >= 720:
            x = int(duration/720)
            y = ((duration%720) * rate)
            if y >= max_rate:
                return((x * max_rate) + max_rate)
            else:
                return((x * max_rate) + y)

cost = get_cost(df)
```

This snippet raises a `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous` error. If anyone has better solutions or could help translate this if/else statement a more pandas way that would be amazing!

Comment: add `print(duration)` and I'm sure you will figure this out

Comment: Hi @TomWojcik are you referring to find where the error is coming from?

Comment: Yes. And a full stack trace would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this solution.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

def get_cost(x):
    t_zone = 720
    max_rate = 5.5
    rate = 0.0208
    duration = x['t1']
    if duration < t_zone:
        if(duration * rate) >= max_rate:
            return max_rate
        else:
            return(duration * rate)
    else:
        if duration >= 720:
            x = int(duration/720)
            y = ((duration%720) * rate)
            if y >= max_rate:
                return((x * max_rate) + max_rate)
            else:
                return((x * max_rate) + y)

df['cost'] = df.apply(get_cost, axis=1)
```

You could also assign result to the same column too. In this case, I have assigned to a custom column called 'cost'.

**Output:**

```
    t1  cost
0   8   0.1664
1   1134    11.0000
2   0   0.0000
3   119 2.4752
4   122 2.5376
5   446 5.5000
6   21  0.4368
7   0   0.0000
8   138 2.8704
9   0   0.0000
```

Comment: thank you so much for you help. This was exactly what i needed!

Comment: Kindly accept the answer in case this was what you were looking for. :)

Answer (score 4):

It is not efficient to use loops and `if` statements in pandas, unless absolutely necessary. Here is a completely vectorized, 100% pandas solution:

```
import numpy as np # Needs numpy, too
x = df['t1'] // 720 * max_rate # Note the use of //!
y = df['t1'] %  720 * rate
df['cost'] = np.where(df['t1'] < t_zone, 
                      np.minimum(df['t1'] * rate, max_rate),
                      np.minimum(y,               max_rate) + x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be iterating over the duration rather than directly comparing it to a number. You could do this.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';')

def get_cost(df):
    t_zone = 720
    max_rate = 5.5
    rate = 0.0208
    duration = df['t1']
    ratecol = []
    for i in duration:
        if i < t_zone:
            if(i * rate) >= max_rate:
                ratecol.append(max_rate)
            else:
                ratecol.append(i * rate)
        else:
            if i >= 720:
                x = int(i/720)
                y = ((i%720) * rate)
                if y >= max_rate:
                    ratecol.append((x * max_rate) + max_rate)
                else:
                    ratecol.append((x * max_rate) + y)
    return ratecol
df['cost'] = get_cost(df)
```

This code produces exact same result as the one posted before.